# Eclipse "forgets" my PyDev interpreter

Tags: eclipse, interpreter, pydev

I've just installed Eclipse and PyDev (again - I've been without it for some time) and everything works like a charm, except one little annoyance:

Every time I start Eclipse, I have to go to Window->Preferences... and configure a Python Interpreter. It's not hard to do (pressing "Auto Configure" works) but for some reason Eclipse seems to forget that I set that setting before, and has me do it every time I start the program.

Is there any way to force Eclipse to remember, or to automatically configure the interpreter on startup? Since AutoConfigure works, Eclipse can apparently do the work on its own - it just doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Eclipse settings directory is not fully writable? Check and see if everything is writable by your user.

And if that doesn't work, you can try starting it with `eclipse -clean`.

And if that didn't help either, you can try removing your profile completely.